# SQL Server 2005 on Windows 7 along with SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Edition

Tags: windows, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, ssms

I've installed SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Edition in my Win 7 notebook. The Express Edition doesn't have SQL Profiler enabled. Thus it's hard for me to debug my SQL 2005 applications.

I have a license for SQL Server 2005 (32 bit) and when I tried to install the client tools it gave a "known compatibility" error message. Is it possible to install the 2005 client tools (for 32 bit) only in the same machine?

I have SQL Server 2008R2 Express Edition, Windows 7, and Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: My advice would be to create VMs for your required testing environments.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/95072/is-it-possible-to-install-ms-sql-2005-on-windows-7 might give you some hints on how to proceed with installing SQL 2005 on Windows 7 since it is supported according to Microsoft http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955725

Comment: Is that "error" message the warning to install the Service pack?